# Permanent redirect all http requests to include www subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I have noticed both google.com and amazon.com, redirect requests to www.google.com and www.amazon.com

I am thinking of doing the same for my website which is hosted on AWS. What is the best approach to do this? I am not sure if it would be better to implement this in *Load Balancer* or *S3*? Also is there any downside to always redirecting to www sub-domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create an S3 bucket and configure static web hosting to redirect the requests to `www` domain.

More details:

Say your main website is `www.example.com` running on multiple EC2's behind an ALB and you want to set up a 301 redirection for `example.com` so that when a user visits `example.com`, he/she will be redirected to `www.example.com`. You don't need to change anything related to your existing main website domain (`www.example.com`). The only thing you need to change is to add an S3 bucket and name it `example.com`, follow the [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-endpoint-host) to set up redirection, and finally change your DNS.

Comment: Are you able to add some more info please?

Comment: Say your main website is `www.example.com` running on multiple EC2's behind an ALB and you want to set up a 301 redirection for `example.com` so that when a user visits `example.com`, he/she will be redirected to `www.example.com`. You don't need to change anything related to your existing main website domain (`www.example.com`). The only thing you need to change is to add an S3 bucket and name it `example.com`, follow the [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-endpoint-host) to set up redirection, and finally change your DNS. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it would be more helpful for the future readers if you move the comment to your answer... at the moment, the main information about the answer is in the comment...

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Yeah, thanks for your suggestion. I have amended my original answer.